# Rails Simple Form DEPRECATION WARNING

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Simple Form 2.0.1
client_side_validations 3.1.4

Problem:

```
"error_class":"DEPRECATION WARNING: [SIMPLE_FORM] SimpleForm.error_class is deprecated and has no effect. (called from error_class at (eval):1)",
"error_tag":"DEPRECATION WARNING: [SIMPLE_FORM] SimpleForm.error_tag is deprecated and has no effect. (called from error_tag at (eval):1)",
"wrapper_error_class":"DEPRECATION WARNING: [SIMPLE_FORM] SimpleForm.wrapper_error_class is deprecated and has no effect. (called from wrapper_error_class at (eval):1)",
"wrapper_tag":"DEPRECATION WARNING: [SIMPLE_FORM] SimpleForm.wrapper_tag is deprecated and has no effect. (called from wrapper_tag at (eval):1)"
```

How to solve?

My view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @book_item, :validate => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
  <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")), book_items_path, :class => 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306811/rails-simple-form-and-client-side-validations-arent-working

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using `client_side_validations-simple_form` gem for SimpleForm integration  but it doesn't work with SimpleForm 2 right now - https://github.com/dockyard/client_side_validations-simple_form/issues/2