# Rails, Simple Form, and Client Side Validations aren't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, client-side-validation

My model:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name
belongs_to :user
has_many :room_types
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :name, presence: true, length: { in: 2..15 }
end
```

The form code:

```
    <%= simple_form_for @hotel, :validate => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%=  f.submit 'Create Hotel' , :class => 'btn btn-primary', :type => 'submit' %>
   <% end %>
```

There doesn't seem to be any client side validation being performed.  I can submit the form without filling in any information.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  Ok, I looked at the source of my page and it has this error:

window['new_hotel'] = {"type":"SimpleForm::FormBuilder","error_class":"DEPRECATION WARNING: [SIMPLE_FORM] SimpleForm.error_class is deprecated and has no effect. (called from error_class at (eval):1)","error_tag":"DEPRECATION WARNING: [SIMPLE_FORM] SimpleForm.error_tag is deprecated and has no effect. (called from error_tag at (eval):1)","wrapper_error_class":"DEPRECATION WARNING: [SIMPLE_FORM] SimpleForm.wrapper_error_class is deprecated and has no effect. (called from wrapper_error_class at (eval):1)","wrapper_tag":"DEPRECATION WARNING: [SIMPLE_FORM] SimpleForm.wrapper_tag is deprecated and has no effect. (called from wrapper_tag at (eval):1)","validators":{"hotel[name]":{"presence":{"message":"can't be blank"},"length":{"messages":{"maximum":"is too long (maximum is 15 characters)"},"maximum":15}}}};

Answer (score 3):

You have to set up `browser_validations` option in your `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` file

```
# Tell browsers whether to use default HTML5 validations (novalidate option).
# Default is enabled.
config.browser_validations = true
```

PS Don't forget to run

```
$ rails g simple_form:install
```

to generate initializer.

Comment: Ok so now the name field starts grey.  When I click into it, it goes red, and then when I type a letter it goes green.  So it's not working, but at least it is doing something now.  Any ideas on how to make it work completely correctly?

Comment: Look for `config.wrappers` section in initializer. There are some options like `b.optional :maxlength`, `b.optional :pattern` and others.

Comment: I changed this to b.use but it didn't seem to change anything:   # Calculates maxlength from length validations for string inputs
    b.use :maxlength

Comment: It seems that you have old version of simple_form gem. What is it?

Comment: 2.0.2 is the simple_form version